# ASP WebAPI can we have optional RoutePrefix?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am wondering if this is possible or not to set the WebAPI RoutePrefix with an optional prefix within the URL? What I am trying to achieve is to be able to pass (or not) optionally the locale language in my WebAPI route. I would like to have 2 possible routes providing the same result.

URL 1 (with locale)
`http://localhost/en-US/api/users/1`

URL 2 (without locale)
`http://localhost/api/users/1`

```
//WebApiConfig.cs
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiWithLanguage",
            routeTemplate: "{language}/api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { language = @"^(([a-z]{2})|([a-z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2}))$" } // can be:: en, en-CA, fr, fr-CA, ...
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I tried adding the following code in my WebAPI Controller:

```
// UserController.cs
[System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix("{language?}/api")]
public class UserController : ApiController
```

It works with the locale provided, but doesn't work without it... I thought the `?` would make it optional, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Can it be done, or is it simply not possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you mixed attribute routing and conventional routing! 
To get this working use conventional routing and remove `RoutePrefix` and any other `Route` attribute from your controller.

Comment: The problem is that if I do it this way, I get the old fashion Route with Controller and Action `http://localhost/api/User/GetUser/1` and I was trying to avoid that